# How to insert php echo on $output variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I need to correct this code, I don't know why my PHP is commented out every time:

```html
$output = '<ul class="custom_code">
    <li class="custom_code">
    <?php echo wpfp_link(); ?>
    </li></ul>';

return $output;
```

Comment: you're already in php `<?php echo wpfp_link(); ?>` so get rid of the PHP tags.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` runs immediately. It doesn't return anything. So your code is effectively running as if it was written like this:

```
echo wpfp_link();
$output = '<ul blah blah blah</ul>';
return $output;
```

Given you're dealing with word<strike>puke</strike>press, you probably want something more like

```
$output = '<ul blah blah ' . get_wpfp_link() . '...</ul>';
return $output;
```

As well, PHP is not resursively embeddable, as you have. This code will not work as you think it would:

```
<?php
echo '<?php echo 'foo' ?>';
?>
```

This will output `<?php echo 'foo' ?>`, not just `'foo'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the string with `.`

```
$output = '<ul class="custom_code"><li class="custom_code">'.wpfp_link().'</li></ul>';

return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = '<ul class="custom_code"><li class="custom_code">'.wpfp_link().'</li></ul>';

return $output;
```

definitely will works. BUT we sure that you don't use short php tags /or they turned on in php.ini

so all this should looks like:

```
function print_li(){
$output = '<ul class="custom_code"><li class="custom_code">'.wpfp_link().'</li></ul>';    
return $output;     
}
```

where wpfp_link returns a list with `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works like this but you can try.

```
$output = '<ul class="custom_code">
 <li class="custom_code">'.wpfp_link().'
</li></ul>';
return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$funcout = wpfp_link();
return "<ul class=\"custom_code\"><li class=\"custom_code\">{$funcout}</li></ul>";
```